# jqGrid - form editing issues

Tags: jqgrid, form-editing

In the inline editing, before the editing be made, it creates internally an array (`savedRow`) and fill it with the values of the fields that are being editable, so I can access this values.

I'd like to know if in the form editing it has something similar to this, because I need to access the values of the fields before the editing will be completed to do a validation before the fields are "saved" in the database.

Someone could help me?

---

**EDITED :**

I'm posting here a part of my code (the code of one field), and I'm trying to validate in both way (inline editing and form editing). For *inline editing* I'm validating using `dataEvents` and there I'm using `savedRow` to access the data that were not stored yet. But when I try to edit using form editing because of the the use of savedRow, it shows me an error: `savedRow is not defined`. In the case of this field the `editrules` fits with what I want to do, but I don't know if this will occurs in all of those fields.

```
{ name: 'ac_fd', index: 'ac_fd', width: 50, editable: true,
  formatter: 'number', editrules: { number:true, required:true, minValue: 0.1,
  maxValue: 1.0 }, formatoptions: { decimalPlaces: 1, decimalSeparator: '.'},
     editoptions: {
        dataEvents: [ {
           type: 'blur', fn: function(e) {                        
              var savedrow  = $("#list").getGridParam('savedRow');
              console.log($(this).val());
              if($(this).val() != savedrow[0]['ac_fd']) {         
                 var eid='#' + savedrow[0]['id'] + '_ac_fd';   
                 var val_fd=$(this).val();
                 var fd_min=0.1;
                 var fd_max=1.0;

                 if( isNaN(val_fd) || val_fd > fd_max || val_fd < fd_min) {
                       setTimeout(function(){
                       $(eid).focus().select();
                    },600);


                    $(eid).qtip({
                       content: {
                          text: 'Fator de Demanda deve ser um <b>número</b>
                                 entre <b>' + fd_min.toFixed(1) + '</b> e <b>'
                                 + fd_max.toFixed(1) + '</b>.',
                          title: {
                             text: 'Atenção:',
                             button: true
                          }
                       },
                       show: {
                          event: false,

                          ready: true,

                          effect: function() {
                             $(this).stop(0, 1).fadeIn(400);
                          },

                          delay: 0,
                                                     },
                       hide: {
                          event: false,

                          effect: function(api) {
                             $(this).stop(0, 1).fadeOut(900).queue(function() {
                                 api.destroy();
                             });
                          },
                       },
                       style: {
                          classes: 'qtip-red qtip-rounded trif_tip_err',
                          tip: {
                             width: 10,
                             height:12
                          } 
                       },
                       position: {
                          my: 'bottom left',  
                          at: 'top center',
                       },

                       events: {
                          render: function(event, api) {
                             tip_timer.call(api.elements.tooltip, event);
                          }
                       }
                    });  

                 }       
              }        
           }           
        } ]            
     }                   
  },
```

So if `dataEvents` is common and used for the three forms of edit, where can I do this type of validation (using qtip too and I want that this validation be used in inline editing too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why jqGrid save the editing row in interval `savedRow` parameter is because jqGrid *modify* the editing row in-place. Only because of that inline editing and cell editing use interval `savedRow` parameter. Form editing don't modifies the original row of grid till the editing will be finished. So no `savedRow` parameter are used by form editing.

If the form are closed or if the server response will contains some error HTTP code the new data entered by user will be not saved in the grid. So simple server side validation is typically enough. If you want implement additional client side validation you can use [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules) feature. [Custom validation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example) is typically enough. It can help validate one field of the form. If you need compare multiple fields of form during validation (if the value of one field defines valid values of another field) then one uses [beforeCheckValues](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#events) callback additionally.

**UPDATED**: Inside of `fn` event handler you can test whether it will be called inside of form editing or not. There are many ways to do this. For example you can test `$(e.target).closest(".FormGrid").length > 0`. If it's true then the event is inside of form. Additionally it's important to understand that the current editing row is *not changed till successful saving on the server*. So you can use any time `getGridParam` with `"selrow"` option to get the id of editing row and you can use `getRowData` or `getCell` to get the data from the grid before modification started (the same as `savedrow`).

Comment: Thanks for reply :)
Hummm I thought that form editing works like in the inline editing, but now I understood. Thank you so much @Oleg! :)

Comment: @mailazs: You are welcome! One large problem of jqGrid is that it contains many code duplicates or many close, but not the same implementations of the same things. Inline editing, Cell editing and form editing has only some part of common functions like `createEl`, `bindEv` and `checkValues` (from [the module](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.common.js). The most main work contains *different implementation in all three editing modes*.

Comment: Huuumm I think they could have thought of implementing the main features in all three modes, like in this case... they could have implemented something that allows you to validate field by field before submit the form. It would be very helpful. :)
I'm having some troubles with these validation because I'm using `dataEvents` to do the validation on inline editing, and in the `dataEvents` I'm using `savedRow`, so this creates me a problem when I'm going to use form editing :( Do you have some suggestion to me?

Comment: @mailazs: I wrote about `editrules` feature in my answer. It's the main way to validate the data. events defined using `dataEvents` can for example control `keydown` and deny for example numbers.

Comment: I saw this but what I'm using is `savedRow` in `dataEvents` and when I try to edit using form editing, it shows me an error that `savedRow` is not defined. What I mean is even with this can I continue using `dataEvents` and `savedRow`, and then use `editrules` for the other validations?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand you. `savedRow` is method of *inline editing*. You wrote about *form editing*. So I don't understand wnat you do.

Comment: I'm sorry... what I mean is: I'm doing an inline editing (and I'm using `dataEvents` to do some validations), and I want to do a validation in form editing too. But when I press the `edit button` in the `navGrid` and I try to edit something, it shows me an error: `savedRow is not defined`. I don't know how to make this two things works... because when I define `dataEvents` I do this in the field right? So how can I managed this!? Am I so confused? Or did you understand me?

Comment: `dataEvents` is *common* callback used in all editing modes. So you have to use here only common features of jqGrid. `savedRow` is nor supported in form editing mode so your code will which use `savedRow` will not work. I would recommend you to post the code which you use instead of to describe it. You can additionally descrine *what kind of validation* you want to implement, why you can't use `editrules` feature etc.

Comment: Ok, Thanks again! I will post in the question :)

Comment: @mailazs: Look at **UPDATED** part of my answer. I hope that you find missing information here.

Comment: I'm sorry... but just one more newbie question... this `fn`is just a function?

Comment: @mailazs: I on't know your exact knowledge. By specifying callback function `fn` you register event handler for `blur` event. jqGrid just  register the event handler like using [the method](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). jQuery supports [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method which uses jqGrid internally (see [the lines](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.4/js/grid.common.js#L268-L273) of code).

Comment: I don't have so much knowledge, I'm trying to learn a bit of javascript, jquery, php, jqgrid, these things... so I don't have much knowledge, this is why I'm asking everything for google and for you hahaha :) Humm I think I understood now! I will search a little bit more! Thanks for your time and your help :)

Comment: @mailazs: If you newcomer in JavaScript I would recommend you to google about *closure* in JavaScript. It's one of the most important and frequently misunderstanding construction of JavaScript especially from people who come from another computer language. It's very important to understand the *time of live* and *scope* of variables in JavaScript. JavaScript code looks close to other computer languages, but works frequently in other way.